# Which official LEGO stores have the largest selection of bricks in their PAB wall?

Tags: shopping, pick-a-brick

Official LEGO stores offer the opportunity to fill a cup (small or large) with LEGO elements from a wall with shelves, usually near the back at the store.
These are called PAB walls (Pick A Brick)

This is often one of the cheapest ways to purchase LEGO elements.

However, the size of the wall and hence the size of the selection, differs from store to store.

I was wondering, which stores have the largest wall ?  In Europe I think it is the one at Disneyland Paris, but I could be mistaken. I'm also interested in other countries/continents...

Comment: Define large. Most unique parts? Most wall space? Do you have a picture of the display in Disneyland Paris for comparison?

Comment: It seems the only sensible criterion would be the number of unique pieces simultaneously offerable, which "size of the wall and hence the size of the selection" seems to be referring to.

Comment: Lego store in the Bullring shopping centre has a display similar in size to that of Disneyland, from a quick Google image search. I don't have a valid answer to submit though.

Comment: From this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xs9LTiRtMGE I count 18 columns for Bullring, according to this site: https://www.brickbuildr.com/index.php/view-store/?store=131 Disney land Paris has 26...

Answer (score 6):

I cannot seem to find the official press release for Berlin flagship store re-opening in 2017, however various sources<sup>[1](https://ixtenso.com/store-design/what-shop-design-can-look-like-the-lego-flagship-store-in-berlin.html), [2](https://zusammengebaut.com/lego-flagship-store-berlin-bilder-der-eroeffnung-29111/)</sup> state at that time it had the **Europe’s largest** ”Pick & Build“ wall. Latest news I could find related to this particular shop wall is [couple of months old](https://www.promobricks.de/lego-store-test-pab-wand/101525/) (in German). There's a picture representing all parts available for PAB with 144 parts/bins.

I've also found following picture on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR8qT.jpg) via [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/lego/comments/6j1r1e/berlin_lego_shop_reopened_as_flagship_store_with/), showing the size of PAB wall

[image]

Comment: 144 parts/bins seems to match with this site: https://www.brickbuildr.com/index.php/view-store/?store=45 however, the disneyland paris seems to have 156 bins, i.e. 2 columns more: https://www.brickbuildr.com/index.php/view-store/?store=131 Anyway, impressive find, you have my upvote...

Comment: How do you pick a brick from the two uppermost rows of bins? There is no ladder nor ladder rails which might indicate an out-of-frame movable one as in some libraries...

Comment: @Davide if you look closely on top rows you may notice bricks and their orientation are the same - they only differ in color. It is just pictures of bricks.